# anyway to change camera publisher topic?

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro, xtion, asus, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys.

I'm currently testing out the Teleop (Hydro) app on my Nexus 10 to control Turtlebot.

Im able to establish the pairing between both parties, and able to control the turtlebot using the Virtual Joystick but unable to view live camera feed.

note that I'm using Asus Xtion Pro Live camera. It is able to display image in rviz (so i take it as it's working)
BUT, there is no topic: /camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed

These are the steps that i made:

1. roscore
2. rocon_launch turtlebot_bringup bringup.concert
3. roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch

okay. so what i find out is.. that the app itself is subscribing to:

> /camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed

but when i run:

> rostopic info
> /camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed

it shows:

> Type: sensor_msgs/CompressedImage
>
> Publishers:
>
> /camera/camera_nodelet_manager
> (http://192.168.1.23:50576/) / this is
> actually my turtlebot ip/
>
> Subscribers:
>
> none

I'm wondering if i need to change there 3dsensor.launch file to manually change the publishing topic so that my nexus can subscribe to it?

if i need to do so, how may i change the launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189089/anyway-to-change-camera-publisher-topic?/) by [syaz nyp fyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/18948/syaz-nyp-fyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can simply remap the topic to another topic by adding this to the line where you start the node in the launch file

```
remap from="oldTopic" to="newTopic"
```

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0